# Nano through Sudoedit = No colors

Tags: colors, nano, sudoedit

Here are my personal aliases for editing root owned files:

```
# CLI superuser nano; compiled; version 2.8.0

function sunano {
    export SUDO_EDITOR='/usr/local/bin/nano'
    sudoedit "$@"
}


# GUI superuser xed; packaged; version 1.2.2

function suxed {
    export SUDO_EDITOR='/usr/bin/xed'
    sudoedit "$@"
}


# GUI superuser sublime-text; packaged; version 3126

function susubl {
    export SUDO_EDITOR='/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -w'
    sudoedit "$@"
}
```

---

Let me take it from end:

1. Sublime Text works great now thanks to [Stephen Kitt's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356119/126755).
2. Xed seems to work good too, it shows that the privileges are elevated, which I personally don't like to be reminded of, but there seems to be no problem with it, colors are there and it didn't even need some *wait* switch like Sublime.
3. The problem I have is with Nano as follows:

   If I invoke it as I was used to, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nanorc
   ```

   The colors are there.

   But if I call it with the new alias:

   ```
   sunano /etc/nanorc
   ```

   There are no colors whatsoever.

   The configuration seems to have been read though, because it looks the same as I've configured it.

**EDIT1:** Apparently this issue affects at minimum the config file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.6K Apr  8 02:30 /etc/nanorc
```

Other files, e.g. Bash or C++ are colored, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `sudoedit` copies the file to a temporary file before opening it in the editor. When the file has an extension, the temporary file is created with the same extension, and filename-based syntax highlighting modes are selected appropriately (*e.g.* for C files). When the file doesn’t have an extension, as is the case with `nanorc`, it is created with a random extension; this confuses filename-based syntax highlighting mode selection, and `nano` ends up treating the file as a standard text file.

If you can reconfigure `nano` to treat any `nanorc*` file as a configuration file, you’ll be able to restore the behaviour you’re after. Otherwise I’m not sure there’s a way to handle this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function sunano {
    export SUDO_EDITOR='/usr/local/bin/nano'
    sudoedit -E "$@"
    #        ^^ 
    #         add this
}
```

`-E or --preserve-env` passes your environment variables to the new process