# The easiest way to bypass "Permission Denied" by file

Tags: ubuntu, command

Is it possible to get a simple answer please?

I need to change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, but it says I don't have root and I am not the owner.

I need the simplest form of instructions to accomplish this please as I'd rather do an internal upgrade where I don't have to be as attentive installing an upgrade as new in the future and all I get on google is stuff like this. A bunch of examples that are no help at all. I'm sort of new with Ubuntu/Linux so this is why I ask for the easiest way. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Past 2012 and 2014 answers for other "permission denied" questions didn't help.

Comment: Which answers didn't help any?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly edit system files (as root) in GUI (and CLI) in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356113/how-to-properly-edit-system-files-as-root-in-gui-and-cli-in-linux)

Comment: How are you trying to edit the file? Which text editor are you using?

Comment: Presumably you do have root, though, because otherwise you're not going to be able to upgrade the system.

Comment: The simplest answer would be to ask the administrator of the system to make this change to the file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I remember in the 1990s when you would be reading a manual, and get to the bit where it said "ask the system administrator", and I would say "but I am the system administrator".

Comment: Proof reading. Right. I did punctuate what was important exactly how it's listed. To answer another one I am the system administrator. Next, tried the default text app. Regardless Ubuntu is denying edit and save permissions for the text file.Lastly, checking reference links provided now

Comment: "To answer another one I am the system administrator." If so then put "sudo " in front of your command and provide the password when asked.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, such manuals are a bit useless. However, in this case they say _I don't have root and I am not the owner_, so there's someone else who's the admin.

Comment: @Kusalananda But I can have more than one role. I can be: me, admin, other.

Comment: That's what i am having the issue with. I do not know what to type as a full command after sudo. I mean it's like the reason I even made this post was due to a tutorial I was following. A few steps with command lines to upgrade Ubuntu internally. Sadly I got a warning that I needed to edit a file. Ironically another tutorial said "hey did you know you can upgrade using software updates? just a couple steps and it's working great. so knowing the location of said release-upgrades file, I'm asking for help on the proper command-line so I can save it to refer to in the future.

Comment: Now I'm confused. The file Ubuntu wouldn't let me save the edit to now has that edit in it. Everything is bound to make me go crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cant add a comment so I have to to it with an answer:

If I understand correctly you are not able to save the system-file if opened via the GUI. The easiest way is to do this in the Terminal.
If you want to change this interactively you could use e.g. `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

If you want to change it without any interactive editor you could use `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^\(Prompt=\).*$/\1normal/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is all I was looking for. Excellent. I highly appreciate your understanding.