# Using Visual Studio Code as EDITOR e.g. with sudoedit

Tags: editors, sudoedit, visual-studio-code

I am using Kubuntu 20.04.

When I run `sudoedit /etc/fstab`, VS Code opens to a blank document and the CLI immediately returns (see details below).

If I run `export SUDO_EDITOR=nano`, the document opens in the nano editor with the contents of `/etc/fstab` as expected.

If I run `export SUDO_EDITOR=/snap/bin/code`, it once again opens VS Code with a blank document.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

---

```
kevin@kevcoder00 ~ $ echo $VISUAL

kevin@kevcoder00 ~ $ echo $SUDO_EDITOR

kevin@kevcoder00 ~ $ echo $EDITOR
/snap/bin/code
kevin@kevcoder00 ~ $ sudoedit /etc/fstab 
[sudo] password for kevin: 
sudoedit: /etc/fstab unchanged
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell the editor to wait:

```
SUDO_EDITOR="/snap/bin/code --wait" sudoedit /etc/fstab
```

Without that option, VS Code forks, or notifies an already-running instance, and control immediately returns to `sudoedit`. The latter sees that nothing has changed and deletes the temporary copy that is used for editing purposes. (Snap might contribute to the effect, but VS Code on its own requires this.)

See also [How to properly edit system files (as root) in GUI (and CLI) in Gnu/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356113/86440)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may try (maybe an overkill solution in your case) my script:

https://github.com/burianvlastimil/sudoedit-enhanced

---

I worked hard to document it well, and the latest, very recent, revision is stable.

In any case, [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)'s [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672665/126755) may be fine.

---

**But**, `sudoedit` does not work well with, specifically, VS Code, unfortunately - as I was asked for details, from comment I quote:

> @StephenKitt Sure. [Here it is](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/sudoedit-enhanced/blob/master/sudoedit-enhanced#L43) from my testing one year ago approx. The only way to edit as `root` with `code` was at that time via `sudo code /path/to/file`. Did something change? I would surely like to know.

Comment: The command given in my answer (replacing `/snap/bin/code` as appropriate) works fine for me (without `--user-data-dir`).

Comment: @StephenKitt Ok, I will try to make time later today to test it. Thank you.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak maybe you some effect of [`sudo` (not) resetting `HOME`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/438564/70524)?