# What is the admin:// prefix and how to make it work?

Tags: debian, gvfs

Looking for an alternative to `gksudo` in Debian, I stumbled upon [this article](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/), which suggests to use the `admin://` prefix in order to access files as root. E.g. instead of

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
```

one is supposed to run

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/apport
```

I don't use `gedit`, but running `leafpad admin:///etc/fstab` on my Debian Buster simply opens an empty file. What am I missing?

`mtp://` is working on that machine, so I suppose GVFS support is present.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a gedit or at least GNOME-specific thing.  GNOME has a lot of extended capabilities around file paths.  I've never heard of it in any other context.  Someone who knows should actually answer though.

Answer (score 8):

`admin:` is one of [GVfs’ schemes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/schemes). It is only usable in editors (and other applications) which support GIO/GVfs; this is one reason why `gedit` is typically used in examples.

As far as I can tell Leafpad doesn’t support GIO, so it can’t use `admin:`.

See also [How to properly edit system files (as root) in GUI (and CLI) in Gnu/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356113/86440)

Comment: So the likely problem is that leafpad doesn't support GIO/GVFs?

Comment: Yes, that’s probably why it’s not working for you.