# Is there such thing as "administrator root"?

Tags: zorin, gvfs

So leaving details aside last night i stumbled across "administrator root" in a live instance of Zorin.

First off, is Administrator Root even a thing? If so, where does it fall into the hierarchy? As i understood it there were three users in linux - root, admin, and user.

Picture is attached.

[image: top lefthand corner]

Thank you.

Comment: "_As i understood it there were three users in linux - root, admin, and user_" - in the general sense that's wrong. The standard name for the administrative user account is "root". There may be zero or more system accounts that exist to help manage separation of privilege. There is usually at least one non-privileged user account, which is available for day to day activities

Comment: Ok, so... root, system, user then?? Have you ever seen an administrator root?

Comment: No, not root, system, user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the admin:// prefix and how to make it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676014/what-is-the-admin-prefix-and-how-to-make-it-work)

Comment: From your screenshot it looks that "Administrator Root" is just a "descriptive" name used by some GUI file browser you are using to describe a particular directory. Probably that directory is just the filesystem root directory (`/`)

Answer (score 38):

***Administrator Root*** does not mean a privilege here, but a special
access to folders whose prefix URI is `admin://` and stands for a GVFS
scheme.

The expression `admin:///tmp/b-i-s-DNkGOLqG` designates
`/tmp/b-i-s-DNkGOLqG/` accessed through a privileged driver provided
that an application uses a scheme capable interface.

So the word ***root*** means *common parent directory*, and the word
***administrator*** means *privileged role*. And IMHO this is not a good
semantic for a working temporary directory.

Comment: This is the correct answer to *the question*.

Answer (score 36):

On unix, there are two kinds of users:

1. root
2. **everyone** else.

root is any username with a UID of 0.  The username is typically `root`, but doesn't have to be, and it is possible to have more than one root account with a different username (e.g. FreeBSD systems have `root` with `/bin/csh` as its shell, and `toor` with `/bin/sh` instead.  They are **both** root, because they are both UID 0 - it is the UID which is important, not the name.  There is only one root, but root can have aliases).

Ignoring security environments like SELINUX (which can limit what root is able to do), root (UID 0) can do anything on the system that the system is capable of - read, write, delete any file or directory, change ownership or permissions of files etc, bind a network socket to ports 0-1023, shutdown or reboot the system, etc.

All other users can only do what their permissions and group memberships allow.  And programs like `sudo` or `su`, can give them some access to some root capabilities by temporarily elevating them to root, or via other mechanisms such as `capabilities` on Linux.

---

NOTE: There is a sub-class of non-root users that are often called "system users".  Despite what the name suggests, they are ordinary users.  They just happen to be created for special purposes like running a particular daemon and owning that daemon's files and directories. e.g. user `lp` for a printer daemon, `ftp` for ftpd, `postgres` for the postgresql database, and many more.  They usually have a disabled password and their shell set to `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` or similar (user `postgres` is a notable exception because it's fairly common to `su` to user postgres to run `psql` for maintenance tasks).

Quite often, system users have a matching or associated "system group", and sometimes a "system group" exists without an associated "system user" (e.g. group `disk` has group ownership of device nodes for disks and partitions in /dev, and those devices are RW by group - meaning that any member of the disk group can read & write and even re-partition or re-format those block devices).

Most Linux systems reserve UIDs and GIDs 1 to 1000 (or 1 to 500, or similar) for system users (and most, but not all, system users have uids & gids within that reserved range). Non-system users, i.e. normal login accounts, get UIDs and GIDs above that reservation.  This is a matter of OS vendor or even local site policy, not inherent to unix itself.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it explains the basics.  Unfortunately, the OP's question is indicative of a generation of sysadmins who learn UNIX/Linux from the confines of a GUI that hides the actual OS from them.

Comment: Obligatory anonymous internet quote: "To err is human, to really screw things up requires root."

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr; `Administrator Root` may be the full name of `root`, just as `John Smith` may be the full name of `smith`.

The `/etc/passwd` file (or whatever it replaces it, e.g. LDAP) has fields for both a short (the first) and a for a long username / comment (the fifth, also called "GECOS field"):

```
smith:x:12007:12007:John &:/home/smith:/bin/sh
```

Some utilities will replace the `&` with the capitalized short name when displaying info about user, etc, turning `John &` into `John Smith`.

Traditionally on unix, `root` was `Charlie &` -> `Charlie Root`, but people don't like that anymore so they changed it to simply `root` (or `Administrator &`).

Comment: I just used vipw to give my root a name! If my baloney can have a first name, why not my super user?! I had never even fingered root before...
Thanks for the history lesson!